# See nothing but white label error page - Spring boot + hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets, spring-boot

There is no mapping to my request  [/] referencing the method allHotels()
Following are my Application and Controller classes.

Application.class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"comexam.example"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

}

HotelController.class

```
@RestController
public class HotelController
{
@Autowired HotelService hotelService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/hotels/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>> allHotels() {
    List<Hotel> hotels = hotelService.getAllHotels();
    if (hotels.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>>(hotels, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Following is the error stack i"m getting.

```
2017-04-19 17:17:23.729  INFO 5808 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-04-19 17:17:23.730  INFO 5808 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
2017-04-19 17:17:23.836  INFO 5808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-04-19 17:17:23.836  INFO 5808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1646 ms
2017-04-19 17:17:24.077  INFO 5808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-04-19 17:17:24.080  INFO 5808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-19 17:17:24.081  INFO 5808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-19 17:17:24.081  INFO 5808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-19 17:17:24.081  INFO 5808 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-19 17:17:24.277  INFO 5808 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@382db087: startup date [Wed Apr 19 17:17:22 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-19 17:17:24.334  INFO 5808 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hotels/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<comexam.example.model.Hotel>> comexam.example.controller.HotelController.allHotels()
2017-04-19 17:17:24.337  INFO 5808 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-04-19 17:17:24.338  INFO 5808 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-04-19 17:17:24.365  INFO 5808 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-19 17:17:24.365  INFO 5808 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-19 17:17:24.402  INFO 5808 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-19 17:17:24.497  INFO 5808 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-19 17:17:24.582  INFO 5808 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
```

Comment: Is your controller in it.exam.training package?

Comment: So you want to access allHotels() using "/" mapping ?

Comment: what about view resolver ?

Answer (score 1):

You have specified **package** to scan so your controller class must be somewhere inside "it.exam.training" package.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"it.exam.training"})
```

To fix this, move HotelController class to for example "it.exam.training.controller".

Comment: Check that they are scaned properly. You can do it by retrieving application context from SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args) and then call .getBeanDefinitionNames() on it.

Comment: HotelController class is in that bean definition list

Comment: Ok. Try to remove @EnableAutoConfiguration beacause it is already included in SpringBootApplication annotation. This might be the reason.

Comment: Tried that but no luck

Comment: :( You can post your application.properties also. Meaby we can find something there.

Answer (score 0):

Move your Applicaiton.class to it.example.training package and your controller to it.example.training.controller try again.

Comment: did you try changing value="/hotels/" to "/hotels"